# Ip cam in JavaScript, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyone here who knows a good js library for streaming ip camera on web side? I own a Wanscam HW0033 Image Compression: H264

Comment: search for web-rtc you might find some libs

Comment: You better should ask at [softwarerecs.SE], this question is off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach is to use combination of `Node.js` and `HTML5`
If you search an online solution i would suggest `instant-webcam`.Seems very promising.